# How do i use a command on multiple objects?

Tags: java

I would like to use `button1.setText("test");` multiple times without repeating the `.setText("test");` for every button. something like this `button1, button2, button3.setText("test");`

Is this a normal question or am i just lazy.

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the buttons in an array for example, iterate on them and call the method :

```
JButton[] buttons = {button1, button2, button3};
for (JButton b : buttons) b.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of buttons

```
for (JButton b : buttons) b.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are lazy.

If you are using Java 8:

```
Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3).forEach(button -> button.setText("test"));
```

But I would prefer:

```
button1.setText("test");
button2.setText("test");
button3.setText("test");
```